# Nested Touchable to handle onPress while parent handles onLongPress

Tags: react-native, event-handling

I have a simple screen with components like this:

```js
<Parent onLongPress={/* do something */}>
 <Child onPress={/* do something */} />
 <Child onPress={/* do something */} />
<Parent>
```

I would like any long press on anything within `<Parent>` to trigger `Parent.onLongPress`, and short press of children to trigger the correspondant `Child.onPress`. I learned from [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system.html) that the parent view can use `View.props.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={(event) => true}` to be the one handling the event, but I cannot find a way to do this only for long press events and not all touch events. I initially expected I would be able to use the event type in `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture` but it seems to always be set to `undefined`.

I created a Snack if someone wants to try out: https://snack.expo.io/@dgellow/arrogant-strawberries.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LongPressGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler` to capture long press event on the parent component.

Before

```
        <Button // custom component
          style={styles.container}
          onLongPress={() => {
            // long press handler
          }}
        >
          {children} // with `onPress`
        </Button>
      );
```

After

```
import {
  LongPressGestureHandler,
  State,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

...
...

        <LongPressGestureHandler
          onHandlerStateChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
            if (nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
              // long press handler
            }
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {children} // with `onPress`
          </View>
        </LongPressGestureHandler>
```

Please note that the direct descendant of `LongPressGestureHandler` should be a `View`.

I almost go with context approach due to multiple deeply nested children that needed to call the `onLongPress` function passed around as props.

If you are using `react-navigation`, you are using `react-native-gesture-handler` already.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here, ideally the child would "release" its hold on the capture of a press event after `onPress` passes and let the parent's `onLongPress` take over, but I've not found a way to do that.

The solution that worked in my instance was to add the same method for `onLongPress` to the parent and the child, so if the child takes over, it uses the method passed to it, and if not then the parent calls the method.

*Note I've got this working in my codebase, but not tried the **specific** example below:*

```js
const onLongPress = () => alert("long press!");
const onPress = () => alert("short press!");

return (
  <Parent onLongPress={onLongPress}>
   <Child onLongPress={onLongPress} onPress={onPress} />
   <Child onLongPress={onLongPress} onPress={onPress} />
  <Parent>
);
```

If the child component you want to add the `onLongPress` & `onPress` to is further down the Native DOM tree, then you can just keep passing that function down (though it does feel a bit messy if it's *many* levels nested deep, but I've found no alternative).